# comparing a database table from a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a stored procedure that compares a database table from a table column in the said database table. I am doing this to make sure every table is listed and known to be there.

I really don't know the code or syntax because really not an sql person.

this is the code I am thinking:

```
use database_name
if 
((SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) = (select SQL_name from MainDBF))
print 'Yess!';--something will be put here
else if ((select table_name from information_schema.tables) != (select SQL_name from MainDBF))
print 'Noo!';--something else will put here
else( print'Pass')
```

I am using sql 2005 btw

Comment: DO you need to compare the structure or the data or the structure and data between two tables?

Comment: the data only although comparing also he structure is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables where name = (select colname from tablename))  
--<Do your Operation here>
```

Comment: i'm trying to make it dynamic i just didn't put it in the question. will try that nonetheless. and tnx

Answer (score 0):

To compare data in two tables you just need the following code:

```
select * from database1.table1
except
select * from database2.table1
```

or you can use simple join

```
select * from database1.table1 t1
full outer join database2.table1 t2 on t1.key- t2.key
```

if t1.key is null then this record exists only in table t2
if t2.key is null then this record exists only in table t1
if t1.key and t2.key is not null than there is a record with this id, you can only check if there is any modyfication

To make this completly dynamic i need few minutes. I will do it for you later.